# jQuery List Filter not working (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running jQuery 1.8.0.min.js

When I start to type into my input box to filter a List, nothing occurs and inside Chrome Debugger, I get the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined

Points to the line:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function (a, i, m) {
            return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toLowerCase().indexOf(m[3].toLowerCase()) >= 0;
        };
```

Code:

```
(function ($) {
    jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function (a, i, m) {
        return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toLowerCase().indexOf(m[3].toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    };
    function listFilter(list) {
        var input = $('#classroomSearch');
        $(input)
          .change(function () {
              var filter = $(this).val();
              if (filter) {
                  $(list).find("a:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().slideUp();
                  $(list).find("a:Contains(" + filter + ")").parent().slideDown();
              } else {
                  $(list).find("li").slideDown();
              }
              return false;
          })
        .keyup(function () {
            $(this).change();
        });
    }
    $(function () {
        listFilter($("#filterList"));
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: I believe it's just the matches. I took it from another post. I wanted to do a Case Insensitive match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery.expr[":"].contains = jQuery.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return jQuery(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
  });
```

I changed it to the above and it now works.

Found it here: https://github.com/nakajima/jquery-livesearch/issues/5